# Coach throws the ball against the referee

Tags: rules, football, officiating

What should the referee do if a coach, during the game, throws the ball such that it hits the referee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the assumption that the ball was thrown deliberately or recklessly, [Law 5](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/27_06_2014_new--lawsofthegameweben_neutral.pdf) means the Referee

> takes action against team officials who fail to conduct themselves in a
>   responsible manner and may, at his discretion, expel them from the field of
>   play and its immediate surrounds

If the ball hit the referee by accident, for example because the coach was attempting to return it to a player and the referee got in the way, then clearly no action should be taken.

Comment: Good answer. How is play restarted if this is done while the ball is in play (ie. a spare ball is thrown)?